# Conditional expectation for random vectors

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

The most general definition of the conditional expectation that I know is the following:

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P )$ a measure space and $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ a random variable. Given a sigma algebra $\mathcal{G}\subset \mathcal{F} $. The conditional expectation $E(X \mid \mathcal{G})$ is an unique random  variable that:

1. $E(X \mid \mathcal{G})$  is $\mathcal{G}-$measurable
2. $\int_B E(X \mid \mathcal{G}) dP = \int_B X dP, \quad \forall B \in \mathcal{G}$.

When $ \mathcal{G}$ is the $\sigma-$algebra generated by a random variable $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, we adopt the notation: $E(X \mid Y)$.

I would like to generalize this definition for random vectors $X = (X_1,...,X_n)$.

The unconditional vector is straightforward: if $\mu_i = E(X_i)$, then $E(X)= (\mu_1,..., \mu_n)$.

In the multivariate case, for example, if $Y = (Y_1,...,Y_n)$, can I conclude the following?
\begin{equation}
E(X\mid Y) = (E(X_1 \mid Y_1), \ldots, E(X_n \mid Y_n))
\end{equation}

How about the case when $Y = (Y_1,...,Y_m)$ with $m>n$?

Comment: The definition of conditional expectation given a sub-sigma algebra you gave is actually [valid for random vectors as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra), you literally just have to replace $\mathbb R$ by $\mathbb R^n$. As for your question on $E[X|Y] $, assuming all the right conditions regarding measurability, it is actually defined as  $E(X|Y) =E[X|\sigma(Y)] $ where $\sigma(Y)$ is the sigma algebra generated by $Y$. This is discussed in the wiki article (and probably this site) as well.

Comment: No, you can't conclude $\mathbb E[X|Y] = (\mathbb E[X_1|Y_1],...,\mathbb E[X_n|Y_n])$ if $X=(X_1,...,X_n),Y=(Y_1,...,Y_n)$. Indeed, if $X_1,...,X_n$ are any i.i.d random variables with $\mathbb E[X_j]=0$ and $Y=(X_{\pi(1)},...,X_{\pi(n)})$ where $\pi:\{1,...,n\} \to \{1,...,n\}$ is any permutation without fixed point, then easily $\mathbb E[X_j | Y_j] = 0$, however $X$ is fully determined by $Y$ so that $\mathbb E[X|Y] = X$. What you can say is that $\mathbb E[X|Y] = ( \mathbb E[X_1|Y],...,\mathbb E[X_n|Y])$ (and it follows immediatelly by definition, see StratosFair comment above)